# Select onchange with keyboard - do not trigger onchange event until focusout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, onchange

I have a select that is bound to a change event so that it will take the user to a new page when a selection is made. It's fine with the mouse, but when I try to make a selection using my keyboard's arrow keys, the change event fires as soon as I press the arrow rather than waiting for me to tab out, so I can only ever select the first option with my keyboard.

```
$selectLocation.on('change', function() {
    location.href = '/data#' + $(this).val().toUpperCase();
});
```

How can I differentiate between a click and a keypress on my change function, or otherwise make the change function not fire on keypress?

Comment: Hey Erica, did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following snippet:

```js
// Sets the redirect based on user activity on #test.
$('#test').on('change', function(e) {
 if ($(this).data('clicked')) {
    // A click was used to change the select box, redirect.
    console.log('clicked redirect');
  }
});

// Sets data-keypressed on #test when the down or up arrow key is pressed.
$('#test').on('keydown', function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  
  if (code === 38 || code === 40) {
    // Reset data-clicked.
    $(this).data('clicked', false);
    // Bind focusout to the redirect.
    $('#test').unbind('focusout').bind('focusout', function(e) {
      if ($(this).val !== '') {
        // An option is selected.
        console.log('keyboard focusout redirect');
      }
    });
  }
});

// Sets data-clicked on #test.
$('#test').on('click', function(e) {
  // Unbind the focusout event added in the change handler.
  $(this).unbind('focusout');
  // Set data-clicked to be used in the change handler.
  $(this).data('clicked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test" data-clicked="false">
<option value="">-- Select an Option --</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

This snippet uses the HTML `data` attribute to set whether or not the select box was changed with a `click`, and sets the `focusout` event on the select box when the select box was changed on `keypress`. The redirect will occur immediately on click selection, but when using the keyboard will only occur when the select box is focused out and a value is selected.

Answer (score 0):

As selection causes (in your case) navigation, the simplest solution is to avoid change event. Instead save initial value and compare against current when clicked or blured.

```js
var defaultValue = $('#select').val();
$('#select').focus();
$('#select').on('click blur', function(event) {
  if (defaultValue === $(this).val()) {
    return
  }
  // no need to save with location.href
  defaultValue = $(this).val()
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="option" id="select">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```